# Reading JSON in AngularJS prints HTML tag as it is

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

This is the  [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3GD9P/4/) file I am trying to get it work.

I have made a simple filter to change the `\n` newline character from JSON to `<br>` to give line break in the HTML, but it doesn't work as expected.

The question is: In the output `<br>` tag is displayed as it is instead of being rendered by browser as as ***line-break***.

So far I have tried to make new filter with the `$sce` variable like

```
angular.module('myApp.filters', [])
  .filter('linebreak', function() {
    return function(text) {
        return text.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
    }
})
.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
            return function(text) {
                return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
            };
        }]);
```

and pipe the filter in the `ng-bind` like:

```
<div ng-bind="data.para | linebreak | to_trusted"></div>
```

but this doesn't dolve the problem. any hints how to tell Browser that 
 is HTML and render it as line break, in this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `$sce` in html you have to use the `ng-bind-html` directive instead of `ng-bind`:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="jsonCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="data in textFile">
            <div ng-bind-html="data.para | linebreak | to_trusted">        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[You can see this working here](http://jsfiddle.net/NEOLPAR/xu9B2/)

Comment: The biggest thing I was missing was Dependency Injection in controller like `controller('jsonCtrl', ['$scope','$sce', function($scope, $sce) {` your fiddle help me understand lots of things. Many many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use  `ng-bind-html` for html binding.

Replace

> ng-bind

To:

> ng-bind-html

See Angular Docs For [ngBindHtml](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)